# Grouping until new node is found in XSLT 1.0

Tags: xml, xslt

I need to group data until a new data element comes and then logic repeats.

My Input XML:

```
<File>
        <Detail>
            <Data>1</Data>
            <Value>4</Value>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Data>1</Data>
            <Value>7</Value>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Data>2</Data>
            <Value>4</Value>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Data>1</Data>
            <Value>5</Value>
        </Detail>
             <Detail>
            <Data>1</Data>
            <Value>1</Value>
        </Detail>
<File>
```

The resultant ouput XML should look like:

```
<File>
        <Detail>
            <Data>1</Data>
            <Value>11</Value>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Data>2</Data>
            <Value>4</Value>
        </Detail>
        <Detail>
            <Data>1</Data>
            <Value>6</Value>
        </Detail>

<File>
```

The Values are added accordingly. As you can see the the data tags with value 1 is grouped separately as they are separated by Data tag 2.

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A common XSLT 1.0 approach to what is essentially a *while* loop is to use tail recursion.  You start by applying a template to the *first* `Detail` element in each group, and each element then applies templates to the next one, etc.

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="1.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <!-- apply templates to the _first_ Detail element in each group -->
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="Detail[
           not(Data = preceding-sibling::Detail[1]/Data)]" />
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Detail element that is not the _last_ one in a contiguous group -->
  <xsl:template match="Detail[Data = following-sibling::Detail[1]/Data]">
    <xsl:param name="runningTotal" select="0" />
    <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::Detail[1]">
      <xsl:with-param name="runningTotal" select="$runningTotal + Value" />
    </xsl:apply-templates>
  </xsl:template>

  <!-- Detail element that _is_ the last one in a contiguous group -->
  <xsl:template match="Detail">
    <xsl:param name="runningTotal" select="0" />
    <Detail>
      <xsl:copy-of select="Data" />
      <Value><xsl:value-of select="$runningTotal + Value" /></Value>
    </Detail>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

The idea here is that the first of the two `Detail` templates will fire for elements that have the same `Data` value as their immediately following sibling, and will accumulate a running total `Value` passed down the chain.  When we reach the *last* element in a group the second template will output the grand total `Value`.  (In the case of singleton groups like the second one in your example, the first element in the group is also the last one so we go directly to the second template with its default `runningTotal` value of zero).

The XSLT 2.0 version is far simpler, as `for-each-group` has native support for grouping contiguous runs:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">

  <xsl:strip-space elements="*" />
  <xsl:output indent="yes" />

  <xsl:template match="/*">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="Detail" group-adjacent="Data">
        <Detail>
          <xsl:copy-of select="Data" />
          <Value><xsl:value-of select="sum(current-group()/Value)" /></Value>
        </Detail>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: If the input XML file is greater that 50 MB, the XML Spy is giving error "XSLT instruction Stack overflow". I think this is because of recursion. But how do I avoid it in XSLT 1.0

Comment: @user3419276 I believe XML Spy supports XSLT 2.0, so try the 2.0 version with `for-each-group` instead.

Comment: But transformation is required in XSLT 1.0 not in XSLT 2.0.

Comment: @user3419276 I'm rather surprised that XML Spy's XSLT processor isn't clever enough to optimize the tail recursion into a loop internally, but anyhow, I've modified my 1.0 version of the stylesheet slightly so now the maximum recursion depth will be the length of the longest contiguous group.

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you could look at it:

**XSLT 1.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:template match="/">
    <File>
        <xsl:for-each select="File/Detail[not(Data=preceding-sibling::Detail[1]/Data)]">
            <Detail>
                <xsl:copy-of select="Data"/>
                <xsl:variable name="start" select="count(preceding-sibling::Detail)" />
                <xsl:variable name="end" select="count(following-sibling::Detail[not(Data=current()/Data)][1]/preceding-sibling::Detail)" />
                <xsl:variable name="n">
                    <xsl:choose>
                        <xsl:when test="$end">
                            <xsl:value-of select="$end - $start - 1"/>
                        </xsl:when>
                        <xsl:otherwise>
                            <xsl:value-of select="count(following-sibling::Detail)"/>
                        </xsl:otherwise>
                    </xsl:choose>
                </xsl:variable>
                <Value>
                    <xsl:value-of select="sum(Value | following-sibling::Detail[position() &lt;= $n]/Value)"/>
                </Value>
            </Detail>
        </xsl:for-each>
    </File>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```